# How to use the SumAll property?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I have a report with a column `TaxBase` printed by a method `TaxBase()`.

At the end of my report section I need to display the Sum of TaxBase column. 
I don't know how!

Maybe the property **SumAll** can help? But, how is it used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the `SumAll` property will help calculate report totals provided you use footer sections.

Your footer section has to have a sum control (of class [ReportSumControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa592857%28v=ax.50%29.aspx)) and reference the summed field in the `DataFieldName` property.

This can done implicitly using an auto design. Take the report `TaxDeviation` as an example. It has the fields `TaxAmount` and `TaxBaseAmount` with the `SumAll` property set. The footer sections are generated at runtime for the grand total footer section and for each sort field with an `AutoSum` property set to `Yes`.

You can see this clearly if you generate the design by choosing "Generate design" on the `ReportDesign1` node.

You can by code reference the generated sums by using `element.sumControl` or `element.sum`. This can for example be used to calculate contribution ratios (using both methods):

```
display ContributionRatio contributionRatioSum()
{
    SalesLine locSalesLine = this.last(tableNum(SalesLine));
    SalesAmount salesAmount = Currency::MSTAmount(element.sum(tableNum(SalesLine), fieldNum(SalesLine,LineAmount)), locSalesLine.CurrencyCode);
    return salesAmount ? 100.0 * dg(salesAmount, element.sumControl(identifierStr(costAmount))) : 0;
}
```

This method calculates the contribution ratio for a sales line sum of `LineAmount` and `CostAmount`.